# How to match two slashes in my rexex pattern

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm trying to come up with a regular expression that separately will catch up to the second slash as the last character (e.g. `/s/test/xxxx/`)

However, I can't guarantee the URLs above to include something else beyond ending with an additional slash E.g. `/s/test/xxxx/yyyy/`

If I use something like this

```
^\/s\/(.*?)\/(.*?)\/
```

The one above works fine for the first pattern, but as soon as I add the `$` to make sure the last (and second) trailing slash is the last character both the cases below are matched.

```
/s/test/xxxx/
/s/test/xxxx/yyyy/
```

What's wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of a negated character class:

```
^/s/[^/]+/[^/]+/$
```

Explanation of the regex (courtesy [this](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%5E/s/%5B%5E/%5D%2b/%5B%5E/%5D%2b/%24)):

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /s/                      '/s/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^/]+                    any character except: '/' (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /                        '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^/]+                    any character except: '/' (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /                        '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Comment: Can you try to elaborate the solution so I can understand what you have done? Thanks

Comment: @AndreaMoro Added one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
^/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/?$
```